# Making Table Visible On click of button

Tags: asp.net

Table2 is invisible and i want to make it visible on click of Register Button.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button Id="btnstudent" runat="server" Text="Student Registraion" OnClick="btnstudent_Click"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnfees" runat="server" Text="Fees"/>
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>

<table ID="Table2" style="visibility:hidden">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="nametxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            Contact No.
        </td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="contacttxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            Course Name
        </td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="coursetxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            Fees
        </td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="feetxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            Address
        </td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="Addresstxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnregister" runat="server" Text="Register"/>
        </td>

         </tr>

</table>
</asp:Content>

//On button Click

protected void btnstudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table2.style.visibility="visible";
    }
```

Getting Error

> Table2 does not exist in current context.

Comment: Formatted the last section of the code (definition of the `btnstudent_Click` function) and of the error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the runat property in your table to make it work

```
<table id="Table2" runat="server">
```

Change in your button click event

```
Table2.style.visibility="visible";
```

To

```
Table2.Visible = true; // to show
```

And use in your page load event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
Table2.Visible = false; // to hide
}
```